# cfindex causing template to be killed

Tags: coldfusion, cfindex

my first question on stack,

I'm running cf10 Enterprise on windows 2003 server AMD Opteron 2.30 Ghz with 4gb ram. Im using cfindex action = update to index over 1k pdfs

I'm getting jvm memory errors and the page is being killed when its run as a scheduled task in the early hours of the morning.

This is the code in the page :

cfindex collection= "pdfs" action = "update" type= "path" extensions = ".pdf" recurse="yes" urlpath="/site/files/" key="D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\site\files"

JVM.config contents

---

java.home=s:\ColdFusion10\jre
application.home=s:\ColdFusion10\cfusion
java.args=-server  -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.home={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/lib -Dorg.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true -Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random -Dcoldfusion.classPath={application.home}/lib/updates,{application.home}/lib,{application.home}/lib/axis2,{application.home}/gateway/lib/,{application.home}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/flex/jars,{application.home}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfform/jars

java.library.path={application.home}/lib,{application.home}/jintegra/bin,{application.home}/jintegra/bin/international,{application.home}/lib/oosdk/classes/win

java.class.path={application.home}/lib/oosdk/lib,{application.home}/lib/oosdk/classes

---

Ive also tried going higher than 1024mb for -Xmx however cf would not restart until i tokk it back to 1024mb

Could it be a rogue pdf or do i need more ram on the server ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Mark A Kruger - thanks Mark Ive edited my question with the contents of the jvm.config file

Comment: You have 4 Gigs of RAM but you are restricting CF to between 256m and 1024m (1 gig).  That is a very low number. Do you have enough overhead (considering everything else on the server) to move to 2gigs?  `-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m` ... Using the same number for both is also advisable. Otherwise your GC operations become an excercise in resizing and reclaiming physical memory.

Comment: I see you tried higher than 1024 without success. One more thing to check - is your 2003 server 32 bit or 64 bit? if it's 32 bit then you won't be able to use much more than 1320m heap size due to the bitness restrictions. If that's the case then your _real_ solution is to move to 64bit.

Comment: Thanks once again Mark for all your help on this. Im now in discussion to get the server upgraded using your comments as my justification :) thanks and happy christmas !!

Comment: Awesome... I'm glad I could help. Let me know if you need formal help on that upgrade. It's what we do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you *probably* need more RAM. CF10 64 bit with 4Gigs of RAM is pretty paltry.  As an experiment why don't you try indexing half of the files. Then try the other half (or divide them up however appropriate). If in each case the process completes and mem use remains normal or recovers to normal then there is your answer. You have ceiling on RAM.

Meanwhile, more information would be helpful. Can you post your JVM settings (the contents of your jvm.config file). If you are using the default heap size (512megs) then you may have room (not much but a little) to increase. Keep in mind it is the max heap size and not the size of physical RAM that constrains your CF engine - though obviously your heap must run *within* said RAM.

Also keep in mind taht Solr runs in it's *own jvm* with it's *own settings*.  Chekc out [this post](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2010/4/4/solr-troubleshooting-coldfusion-9) for information on that - though I suspect it is your CF heap that is being overrun.